# Salesforce Web to Lead Form text area field not submitting

Tags: salesforce

I have a salesforce web to lead form. Everything seems to be going through to salesforce except the comments textarea box. Any idea why just this field wouldn't work?

The code for the texarea field (there is an actual number in id and name)

```
    <form class="sf-form" id="contact-1"        
    action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?
    encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

    <div class="sf-left">
    <label class="sf-label">First Name</label><input class="sf-text" 
    id="first_name" type="text" maxlength="40" name="first_name" 
    size="20" />
    <label class="sf-label" for="last_name">Last Name</label><input     
    class="sf-text" id="last_name" type="text" maxlength="80" 
    name="last_name" size="20" />

    <label class="sf-label" for="email">Email</label><input class="sf-
    text" id="email" type="text" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" 
    />

    <label class="sf-label" for="phone">Phone</label><input 
    class="sf-text" id="phone" type="text" maxlength="40" name="phone" 
    size="20" />


    <label class="sf-label" for="company">Company</label>
    <input class="sf-text" id="company" type="text" maxlength="40" 
    name="company" size="20" />

    </div>

    <div class="sf-right">

    Comments:<textarea  name="000number here" id="same 000number here" 
    class="sf-textarea" rows="10" type="text" wrap="soft" ></textarea>
    <br> 

    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="sf-submit">

    </div>

    <div class="clearfix"></div>

    </form></div>
```

In debug mode I am getting the following for the textarea field

```
    xxxxxxxx(some long number here): This is another test to get the debug code(long number here): Whatever I put in comments
```

I'm not sure if those long numbers have to do with their account, I'm not familiar with salesforce... are they debug codes?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting that debug message from? Are you using the developer consoles debug log?

Comment: Yes, I am testing it on a WordPress site in debug mode and when I submit the form, that is what outputs for the textarea field. All other fields are fine it'll say Name: name, Last name: last name etc. phone: 555555 etc... but those are all input fields.

I also notice that all the input fields have <label> for the field label, but the comment field does not as shown above.

Comment: Actually sorry, I am not using the developer console. I am just testing it on their WordPress site.

Comment: Are you using the native Salesforce Web To Lead form, or one that you have modified? Can you include the entire forms HTML in the question? (Remember to obscure your OrgId and any other sensitive information)

Comment: I am using the salesforce code given to me from the client which they got from salesforce.. all I added were some classes, but I didn't change any id's or classes in the textarea. Like i said everying is going through just not that textarea field. Updated the code above.

Comment: The `Id` in the text area should start with "00N" and be 15 or 18 characters long. It is the unique field identifier for the target Salesforce field. You or your associates working with Salesforce should ensure this is the correct ID for the target Org Id and that there are sufficient permissions to write to this field.

Comment: yes that is right. The ID is 15 characters long and starts with 00N. Does the comments come into a different area? So does the 'Name' in the textarea

Comment: Is Salesforce that "comments" that you are populating via web 2 lead here are going into a custom field. I.e. this is a field that has been created specifically for this Salesforce Organization and isn't a standard field like last_name. The value from the textarea should be posted into the custom field in Salesforce with the 00N... Id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahh. Well the client was showing the form to Salesforce (they wouldn't give me access) and I guess it is working now. That must've been the issue, because I haven't changed anything on my end. Thanks for your time! –  Beth 2 mins ago